# npm run serve: Site cannot be reached from other computers

Tags: vue.js, npm, raspberry-pi, npm-run

I have installed vue new and I runned `vue create ...`. Then I've tried to reach the site at `localhost:8080` (as it was told in the console) directly from my Raspberry Pi I'm working on. Furthermore I've reached the site at the IP-address of my Raspberry Pi, also directly in the web browser on my Pi.

Why can't I reach this site (with the `IP-address:port(8080)`) from another computers (I've already tried my mobile and my computer)?

Comment: Could be a router/firewall setting.  Are both devices on the same LAN?  Are you able to `ping` the IP of the Pi from your computer?

Comment: Yes, I do: It takes 5ms

Comment: I'm in an SSH-session with the Pi; can that be the problem?

Comment: That should be fine.  Maybe try `nc -l -4 8080` on the Pi and `echo test | nc <ip>:8080` from your PC.

Comment: GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1585587395081 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.100:8080
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Raspbian Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://192.168.2.100:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7